# Adding a new component in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and WPF. I wanna add the following element in the page.

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="99" MouseMove="Variable_MouseMove" x:Name="VariableLabel">
     <Run 
          Background="red" 
          Text="Variable" 
          x:Name="Variable"
     />
</Label>
```

I wanna add it dynamicly to the Canvas, like that:

```
Label label = new Label();
Run r = new Run();
label.Children.add(r);    // error: label doesn't have the definition of Children
canvas.Children.add(label);
```

I want to set the background color behind only the text, rather than the whole label, so I use Run as Label child element and set the child element's background.

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you please add some more explanation. Where do you wish to put 'component'? On Form, under the label? Which component is it, TextBlock, TextBox?

Comment: If there is a fixed amount of components, define them in xaml and use visibility to show and hide them when needed

Comment: If you would take a look at the documentation of the Label class, you would realize that it does not have a Children property. Set its Content. For a Run content, better add it to the Inlines collection of a TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

The label don't have Children but in you case you can use Content. So

```
label.Content = run;
```

will work